# Spring Boot Server display name customize

Tags: hosting, url-routing, embedded-tomcat-7

I would like to change the **SpringBoot Application URL**.

As my current **application.properties** file looks like this :

> spring.application.name=MyApplication
>
> server.port=9090

and the directory structure is

src/main/resources/static/ui/index.html

src/main/resources/application.properties

So , while running the application, I need to do

```
http://localhost:8080/ui/index.html
```

as static directory is directly map to public directory.

But the issue is , I don't want see this : I would like to access the application as :

**http://myurl.com** and it should be map to above url i.e.  **http://localhost:8080/ui/index.html**

How can I achieve this, ***As Spring boot contains embedded tomcat container***.

If I can't achieve this, suppose I buy I domain name, then how to map domain name with this url.

> I tried with dummy domain name mapping, it maps successfully but when
>   it resolves the actual url is displayed in the browser. It show entire
>   url i.e **http://192.168.1.102:8080/ui/index.html** whereas I need
>   **http://myurl.com/index.html**.

I have look around https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
for spring boot application properties fields but didn't find any solution. as server.display-name also didn't worked for me.

If I buyied myurl.com how to map it with Spring boot application if my application is running on cloud.

Thank you in Advance. Examples are appreciated. :)

Comment: You need to register your ip with DNS with name as myurl.com

Comment: yeah, say I have register then do we need to change any settings in our application .
Because I tried with some dummy domain name , it successfully navigates to my application. But still it shows complete url i.e. 192.168.1.102:8080/ui/index.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring. You have a webapplication that communicates via HTTP. From that on, what you need is figuring out how to route the traffic via specific URLs.

Comment: I have seen an example where they can configure their local domain name https://github.com/tobiasflohre/movie-database , so I am confused , how they do in Spring project

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, if possible please help me too, to resolve this issue.